# Project in Spring Tool Suite report "Unable to load annotation processor factory"

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

My project in Spring Tool Suite report Unable to "load annotation processor factory 'org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor' for project XXX", My project runs fine, but I do not want to see this error.I did a lot of searching, but I could not find any result.
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 42):

Delete the `.factory` file from the project root directory.

Comment: Couldn't find .factory. So deleted .factorypath and it worked.

Comment: I had this issue and your simple/easy fix worked for me.

Comment: i deleted ` .factorypath` , it worked

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the spring boot configuration processor to your project; when using maven add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

You find more information in the [spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, In  my  project ,I have the above dependency and  the problem exist.

Comment: Me too. I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse, not Spring Tools Suite, but maybe this will still be helpful..

Eclipse reported the following as an APT Problem:

> Unable to load annotation processor factory '/path/to/gradle/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/2.4.4/12575686ba3820571ea79bfd08d6d27534b97a0e/spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.4.4.jar' for project ...

The version of the annotation processor factory in the error message was from an older version of Spring Boot. The project had been migrated.

I opened project properties `Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing -> Factory Path` and removed the old spring-boot-configuration-processor jar from the list, and the error went away. The correct jar was there already.

Answer (score 0):

After much trouble trying to fing a working answer for this error, I finally found the way myself:

In `Project Properties` > `Java Compiler` > `Annotation Processing` > `Factory Path`

1. Enable `project specific settings`;
2. [Apply and Close];
3. re-Build the Project;
4. Go again in `Factory Path`;
5. Disable `project specific settings`;
6. [Apply and Close].

The error messages will go away.

[image]